# Extra vowel sound between t and m?

Tags: pronunciation

I am listening to a song and I hear an additional vowel sound in the chorus. After checking the lyrics normally should not be there. The lyrics says that line is '*Don't let me drown ...*', but what I hear is rather something like this:

*... dont let **-extra vowel sound-** me drown ...*

Is it only to make the song sound nicer, or is it a common occurrence between t and m? The [link](https://youtu.be/EKF6ghfcQic?list=RDEKF6ghfcQic&t=79) to the song timed at the aforementioned line in the chorus. Another [link](https://youtu.be/EKF6ghfcQic?list=RDEKF6ghfcQic&t=209) to the same line in the chorus later in the same song.

Comment: To be honest, I don't hear the extra vowel.

Comment: I hear it, but I think it's just to make the vocals flow more smoothly.  We get a lot of questions about song lyrics here, but in general, songs are a really bad way to learn anything about "normal" English grammar or pronunciation, because lyrics are written and sung mostly to sound good and fit the meter of the song, not to be strictly correct.